# I want to click on the next element in Python Selenium. I can't click because of shadow dom. What should I do?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, shadow-dom

I want to click on the next element in Python Selenium.
I can't click because of shadow dom. What should I do?
My code is this and the corresponding html is this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KqevB.png)

```
browser.get('https://ownist.kr/member/login.html')
time.sleep(5)

iframe = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/iframe[3]')  # Replace with the actual XPATH
browser.switch_to.frame(iframe)

def expand_shadow_element(element):
  shadow_root = browser.execute_script('return arguments[0].shadowRoot', element)
  return shadow_root

#the above becomes 
shadow_section = expand_shadow_element(browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="ch-shadow-root-wrapper"]'))
shadow_section.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,".PopupCloseBtn__CloseButton-ch-front__sc-14jjsiy-1 fOmWsj").click()
```

Thank you in advance

I click on an element in the shadow dom, but it doesn't work well.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your shadow-root is not placed in iframe
2. Locator of shadow-root is incorrect

Shadow-root host in your case is `#ch-plugin-entry div`.

Also, your modal is appeared async

```py
driver.get('https://ownist.kr/member/login.html')
sleep(10)

dialog = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'#ch-plugin-entry div')))
shadow_section = expand_shadow_element(dialog)
shadow_section.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[class*=PopupCloseBtn]").click()
```

But this is not good approach for case to close your modal.

I suggest to hide it via JS. This would allow you not to sleep for waiting it.

```py
driver.get('https://ownist.kr/member/login.html')

dialog = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'#ch-plugin-entry div')))
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].style.display = "none";', dialog)
```